# Should I have one edit form component for all instances of a certain object or one for each?

Tags: reactjs, vue.js

I'm building a dashboard with vuejs and vuetify, but this is a personal choice that doesn't affect my question.

In a certain page, I have a list of objects, this could be anything, product, user, article.
These objects are editable, by the user of the dashboard I'm building.

Right now, I have one `v-dialog` that has the edit form component in it. And whenever the user clicks on the edit button of one of the objects, I initialize this form with the data of that instance and show it to the user. I thought this would make the website lighter.

But I'm also wondering if this is a premature optimization, because this practice does make my code much more spaghetti like than if I had just copied the form component for every object and show the corresponding dialog and form for each of them.

I thought I'd come here and ask more experienced people what they would do for such scenario. I can imagine that if there are like 100 instances in the list, my optimization would make sense. but for less than 10 instances, I guess it doesn't make that much sense? what do you people think? What is the best practice for this?

Comment: Besides being opinion-based, such refactoring/etc. questions are highly context- and requirement-dependent. If there's any pasta products involved it's unlikely to be worthwhile, or indicates that the refactoring is hitting the wrong spots.

Comment: @DaveNewton can you elaborate what you mean by hitting the wrong spots.

Comment: @DaveNewton I'm not only concerned with the refactoring, I generally would like to know the best practices in handing the form component for a long list of editable objects.

Comment: "Best Practices" is too generic for SO. Which mechanism is chosen is arbitrary; do whatever is easiest, cleanest, and meets your requirements. Re: refactoring--if a refactoring introduces a much higher pasta factor then *how* it was refactored should be examined. There may be other ways to extract functionality that off-load complexity into utilities, components, etc. so the primary refactoring stays clean.